# Changing font in fontspec breaks lua filters

Tags: luatex, fontspec, lua

I’m using  `luaquotes` [which I developed] to add smart quotes to text. This works fine, up until I change the font. The package adds lua filters which replace quotation punctuation. For a reason I can’t tell, when I change the font mid document, these filters stop working. Why is this, and how can  I fix it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luaquotes}
\directlua{}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes X}
\newfontface\mycenty{TeX Gyre Schola X}
%\DeclareTextFontCommand{\mycenty}{\centy}

\begin{document}

 

"The ultimate question to be decided in determining the date of separation is whether either or both of the parties perceived the rift in their relationship as final. The best evidence of this is their words and actions. (The husband's and the wife's subjective intents are to be objectively determined from all of the evidence reflecting the parties' words and actions during the disputed time in order to ascertain when during that period the rift in the parties' relationship was final. [\ldots]"


\mycenty\smartquotes

The ultimate question to be decided in determining the date of separation is whether either or both of the parties perceived the rift in their relationship as final. The best evidence of this is their words and actions. (The husband's and the wife's subjective intents are to be objectively determined from all of the evidence reflecting the parties' words and actions during the disputed time in order to ascertain when during that period the rift in the parties' relationship was final. [\ldots]"



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if I remove `\mycenty` from the middle I see the same quotes? is the second paragraph supposed to start with `"` like the first?

Comment: Sorry it’s the single quotes/apostrophes that break—oddly only the single quotes?

Comment: I didn't trace all your code mostly you are using input buffer callback which is not affected by a font change but you are also making global changes to font features, which would be but I wasn't sure why, aren't you mostly changing `'` to `U+2019`  via gsub string replacements? (sorry I have no local tex this weekend to try it)